# How can i integrate my compressed scripts from Webpack to my Wordpress website

Tags: webpack

I have compressed my scripts, styles with webpack and connected them through **functions.php** with `wp_enqueue_script`. Like this `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "sparkle_project_scripts_include");`

`function sparkle_project_scripts_include(){`

`wp_enqueue_script (  'child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/theme.js');}`

When i view my page, it does show the correct source etc, but it doesn't use them. It is there but isn't used.

**This is the folder, which i have connected with functions.php**
I am using Visual Studio Code, and the function names are colored gray, like nothing is using them.

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./resources/theme.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./resources/js/script.js":
/*!********************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/js/script.js ***!
  \********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {



// window.onload = function() { //active nav item                     Nestrādāja live versijā
//   var current = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
//   if (current === "") return;
//   var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-items a');
//   for (var i = 0, len = menuItems.length; i < len; i++) {
//       if (menuItems[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(current) !== -1) {
//           menuItems[i].className += "active";
//       }
//       console.log(menuItems[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(current));
//   }
//   console.log(current);
// };

function activeNav(){
    var current = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    if (current === "") return;
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-items a');
    for (var i = 0, len = menuItems.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(current) !== -1) {
            menuItems[i].className += "active";
        }
        console.log(menuItems[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(current));
    }
    console.log(current);
  }
  
  function openNavbar() { //Mobile Nav Bar
      var x = document.getElementById("topNav");
      var y = document.getElementById("hamburger");
      if (x.className === "nav-items") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "nav-items";
      }
      if (x.className === "nav-items responsive"){
        y.className = "cross";
      } else{ y.className = "hamburger" }
  
    }//Mobile Nav Bar
  
  
  //Big Video Player
  function playVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementById("big-video");
    var playerBtn = document.getElementById("svg-box");
    var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
    if (video.paused == true) {
      // Play the video
      video.play();
      playerBtn.style.opacity = 0;
      triangle.style.opacity = 0;
    } else {
      playerBtn.style.opacity = 1;
      triangle.style.opacity = 1;
      video.pause(); 
    }
  };

  
    function submitForm(){ //Thank You After Form
      var x = document.getElementById("thank-you");
      var y = document.getElementById("formBtn");
      var g = document.getElementById("checkbox");
      var h = document.getElementById("acceptTerms");
      var c = document.getElementById("obligation");
      
      x.style.display = "none";
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";
        g.style.display = "none";
        h.style.display = "none";
        c.style.display = "none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }//Thank You After Form
 
  
  //MAP variables
  var map;
  var mapStyle = [   //KARTES STILS
    {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#E8E8E8'}]},
    {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{visibility:'off'}]},
    {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#AEAEAE'}]},
    {
      featureType: 'administrative.locality',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#4f4f4f'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{visibility:'off'}]
    },
    { featureType: 'poi',
      stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    },
    { featureType: 'transit',
      stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.arterial',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.arterial',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#E4E4E4'},  ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.arterial',
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{visibility:'off'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#f0f0f0'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#DBDBDB'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'road.highway',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'transit',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
    },
  
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{color: '#D3D3D3'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
      stylers: [{color: '#D3D3D3'}]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
      stylers: [{color: '#D3D3D3'}]
    },
  
  ];
  var locations = [  //VISAS LOKĀCIJAS
    [PURCH = {lat: 56.958002, lng: 24.190948}],
    [KURTS = {lat: 56.951089, lng: 24.121023}],
    [AUCH = {lat: 56.965196, lng: 24.140531}],
    [rand1 = {lat: 56.965314, lng: 24.140524}],
    [rand2 = {lat: 56.965192, lng: 24.130531}],
    [rand3 = {lat: 56.963242, lng: 24.120125}],
    [rand4 = {lat: 56.962343, lng: 24.110536}],
    [rand5 = {lat: 56.965133, lng: 24.10132}],
    [rand6 = {lat: 56.938374, lng: 24.09}],
    [rand7 = {lat: 56.939374, lng: 24.9}],
    [rand8 = {lat: 56.941374, lng: 24.49}],
    [rand9 = {lat: 56.942374, lng: 24.29}],
    [rand10 = {lat: 56.947374, lng: 24.69}],
  ];
  var contentString = [///nestrādā
    ['<h1>PURCH</h1>'],
    ['<h1>KURTS</h1>'],
    ['<h1>AUCH</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand1</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand2</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand3</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand4</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand5</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand6</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand7</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand8</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand9</h1>'],
    ['<h1>rand10</h1>']
  ]; ///nestrādā
  
  
   function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map){ ///Pietuvināšana un attālināšana
     controlDiv.style.padding = "5px";
     controlDiv.style.marginRight = '67px';
     controlDiv.style.marginBottom = '91px';
     if (window.innerWidth < 900){
      controlDiv.style.display = 'none';
     } else{
      controlDiv.style.display = 'block'
     }

    var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    controlWrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlWrapper.style.textAlign = 'center';
  
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);
  
    // Set CSS for the zoomIn
    var zoomInButton = document.createElement('div');
    zoomInButton.style.width = '57px'; 
    zoomInButton.style.height = '57px';
    zoomInButton.style.marginBottom = '22px';
    zoomInButton.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 168, 0, 0.9)';
    zoomInButton.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    zoomInButton.style.borderColor = '#ffaa00';
    zoomInButton.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    zoomInButton.style.borderRadius = '14px';
    /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
    zoomInButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/assets/img/+.png")';
    zoomInButton.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    zoomInButton.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomInButton);
  
     // Set CSS for the zoomOut
     var zoomOutButton = document.createElement('div');
     zoomOutButton.style.width = '57px'; 
     zoomOutButton.style.height = '57px';
    //  zoomInButton.style.marginBottom = '22px';
    zoomOutButton.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 168, 0, 0.9)';
    zoomOutButton.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    zoomOutButton.style.borderColor = '#ffaa00';
     zoomOutButton.style.borderWidth = '1px';
     zoomOutButton.style.borderRadius = '14px';
     /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
     zoomOutButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/assets/img/-.png")';
     zoomOutButton.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
     zoomOutButton.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
     controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomInButton);
     controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomOutButton);
  
       // Setup the click event listener - zoomIn
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInButton, 'click', function() {
      map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    });
  
    // Setup the click event listener - zoomOut
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOutButton, 'click', function() {
      map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    });  
  
  
   }//Pietuvināšana un attālināšana
  
  
   var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 56.952814, lng: 24.113891 },
    zoom: 13,
    disableDefaultUI:true,
    styles: mapStyle,
  }
  var icon1 = "/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/marker.png";
  var icon2 = "/assets/img/marker-dark.png";


/***/ }),

/***/ "./resources/scss/style.scss":
/*!***********************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/scss/style.scss ***!
  \***********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ "./resources/theme.js":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/theme.js ***!
  \****************************/
/*! no exports provided */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "jquery");
/* harmony import */ var jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var _scss_style_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./scss/style.scss */ "./resources/scss/style.scss");
/* harmony import */ var _scss_style_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_scss_style_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
/* harmony import */ var _js_script__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./js/script */ "./resources/js/script.js");
/* harmony import */ var _js_script__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_js_script__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__);
// window.$ = window.jQuery





__webpack_require__(/*! ./scss/style.scss */ "./resources/scss/style.scss");
__webpack_require__(/*! ./js/script.js */ "./resources/js/script.js")


/***/ }),

/***/ "jquery":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** external "jQuery" ***!
  \*************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = jQuery;

/***/ })

/******/ });
//# sourceMappingURL=theme.js.map
```

**And this is the file from where all the JS and css is coming** (/resources/theme.js)

```js
// window.$ = window.jQuery

import './scss/style.scss';
import  './js/script';

// require('./scss/style.scss');
// require('./js/script.js')
```